# Where do I direct download for 11.10/11.04?

Tags: 11.10, wubi, source-code

I have downloaded the wubi for 12.04, but here its showing downloading ubuntu-12.04-wubi-amd64.tar.xz! why amd64 when I selected 32 bit for windows???
Please provide me any source [wubi] to download ubuntu 11.10/11.04 that would be compatible to my windows xp.

Comment: as per your description possibly you are asking for download link. Please feel free to rollback if you are asking for source code.

Answer (score 1):

For downloading 11.04 version , 11.10 version simply browse through this [**page**](http://releases.ubuntu.com/) , select the 11.10 directory for 11.10 version , you will find [**wubi**](http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.10/wubi.exe) at the end of that listing, you can similarly download for 11.04 version.

As per this [page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide/)

> Why is the AMD64 version of Ubuntu being downloaded and installed?
>
> The machine you are trying to install Ubuntu on is 64 bit. The AMD64
>   installation is appropriate for all 64 bit architectures, no matter if
>   they are AMD or Intel.

Answer (score 0):

Press this link to download the [32bit image of Ubuntu 12.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?distro=desktop&release=lts&bits=32). Unpack it with 7-Zip (or any other tool) and run the "wubi.exe" file.

Here is also a [guide for installing Ubuntu within Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows)